# SQL - Proper "where" clause for current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Which is the proper way of checking events from current month on SQL Server and why?

1) `WHERE (DATEDIFF(month, EventTime, GETDATE())=0))`

2) `WHERE (YEAR(EventTime) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(EventTime) = MONTH(GETDATE()))`

Date format in table is i.e. `EventTime: 2011-11-30 15:68:25.000`

Comment: Note : The Data Types DATETIME, etc, don't have formats such as that.  That's just the format used to represent them on screen, as we humans don't like reading binary, etc.  If, however, they are *actually* stored in the table as strings (NVARCHAR, etc), the format does matter and this will hit performance badly.

Comment: @Dems ah, no, it's a datetime format, not varchar, no worries :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have access to a SQL Server with a profiler, so I can't actually give as detailed an answer as I'd like.

The question is basically about which one allows the least calculation and most effective use of indexes.

Variants that use string manipulation have the highest calculation load, and don't use indexes at all.  So I'll just skip those.  That leave four common expressions...

```
SELECT * FROM date_sargable
WHERE  YEAR(value) = YEAR (getDate())
  AND MONTH(value) = MONTH(getDate())
;

SELECT * FROM date_sargable
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, value, getDate()) = 0
;

SELECT * FROM date_sargable
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, value) = DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getDate())
;


SELECT * FROM date_sargable
WHERE value >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getDate())    , 0)
  AND value <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getDate()) + 1, 0)
;
```

The first three use INDEX SCANs, but the last one uses an INDEX SEEK.  The difference is that the format of the query allows the optimiser to know you want a specific range of the data, that it's all next to each other in one block of the index, and that it's very easy to find that block.

If, when looking at execution plans, you see a SEEK in one version, and a SCAN in another, you're much more likely to benefit from the SEEK.

Comment: Thanks. So to put it simply, it's a matter of BETWEEN condition? Not to compare each record but to to get a range?

Comment: BETWEEN is `>=` AND `<=`.  I prefer to use `>=` AND `<`.  That is because I then don't have to care if the data is store to the day, minute, millisecond, etc.  It works no matter what the accuracy.  But other than that, yes, ranges normally perform best in my experience.

Comment: @Seph : Define pointless? Without the DateAdd() you just have the number of months provided by the DATEDIFF().  You can't even implicitly cast that to a date.  Also, note: not all functions obfuscate the index from the optimiser.  From recollection; DATEDIFF() for example is still sargable.

Comment: If the down-voter reads this, please could you comment on why, so that I can deal with the problem?

Answer (score 4):

> Write queries for continuous periods as explicit range condition.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates

Thus, use something like this:

```
WHERE EventTime between <begin-of-month> and <end-of-month>
```

Example code is available at the same page, although doing quarterly filtering:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates?dbtype=sqlserver#sample_quarter_begin_end

**Why?** To make indexing easy.

Comment: I dont understand how this does make anything easier. If following the example, sql server needs to perform 4 queries instead of just one: executing quarter_begin twice, quarter_end once and finally the actual query ofc. Whilst I do not have enough data, and perhaps knowledge, to test this properly, I would suspect this to be actually slower than either of the solutions the OP provided. And apart from any speed questions - it does make the whole query a lot more complicated imho.

Comment: @Sascha Hennig - the functions (quater_end/begin) are executed once only, before the actual query starts. You can also calculate the boundary dates (quater end/begin) in your application, if you prefer that. That does not make a real performance difference. It makes indexing much easier, because the query can use a straight index on EventTime, will will, in turn, outperform any of the other suggested variants.

Comment: Agreed: Calculating the Scalar Constants for the range may use 'alot' of text, but it uses almost none of the query cost.  The biggest costs in databases are often reading from disk, this method ensure the minimum amount of disk reading, reducing redundant reads to as near to 0 as you can get (SEEKing).  The alternatives have many redundant reads (SCANing).

Comment: @Markus Winand - Yes, even though the functions are executed additionaly, they only add a fraction to the performance costs. The main problem I kind of had was the comparable complexity - but then my example was tried and tested on a tiny 4 tuple table =D So yes, it does make sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, they both are.

However, I think the first one is simpler (one condition instead of two), easier to understand and more likely to be sargable - so I suggest using that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on that column, then both calculations are bypassing the index because you're not using what the column is indexed on, but only a part of the index

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(month, EventTime, GETDATE())=0))
WHERE (YEAR(EventTime) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(EventTime) = MONTH(GETDATE()))
```

You are much better off using something like this

```
WHERE EventTime BETWEEN Cast (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()) as Date)
                AND Cast (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,GetDate()))),DATEADD(mm,1,GetDate())) as Date)
```

You can also use the same concept with a `>=` and `<=` for the dates

Answer (score 0):

One tip very simple using [to_char](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) function, look:

At date example:

> 2011-11-30 15:68:25.000

you can do this:

> to_char(your_field , 'MM') = 11

or for current month of system date:

> to_char(***sysdate*** , 'MM') = 11

One detail, **to_char** funcion is suported by sql language and not by one specific database.